# Changing the day value of a selected date via datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I've been trying to get this to work and am stumped.  I'm trying to change the day value of a date selected by the datepicker.  So, for example, if the user selected '5/15/2011' as the date, then I want to change it to '5/1/2011'.  I currently have the following in the page.

```
$('#<%= TextStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({ maxDate: "+0D", minDate: "-24M" });
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [dateFormat](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats) to `m/1/yy`

This will replace the value for the day with 1 and format the date with the US format in your question.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HSzJ9/3/

Answer (score 1):

to set the value of the datepicker just:

```
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```